# React Native - Cameraroll does not showing pictures

Tags: javascript, react-native, gallery

I am trying to show gallery images in my react native app but it does not showing any thing.
Here's my code which I did for the gallery images.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text,View } from 'react-native';

import CameraRollPicker from 'react-native-camera-roll-picker';

export default class Gallery extends Component{
    getSelectedImages(image){
        if(image[0])
            alert(image[0].uri);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <CameraRollPicker callback={this.getSelectedImages}/>
        );
    }
}
```

When I run this into emulator/simulator or to my devices, it only shows a loader.

If anyone know the answer please help me.

Comment: Did you link the project to native side?

Comment: link to native means? I can use Android Studio and Xcode to do changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and here is my code :

```
<CameraRollPicker
    scrollRenderAheadDistance={10000}
    initialListSize={1}
    pageSize={3}
    batchSize={5}
    maximum={3}
    selected={this.state.selected}
    assetType='All'
    imagesPerRow={3}
    imageMargin={5}
    callback={this.getSelectedImages} 
    selectSingleItem
/>
```